# The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION when ran UDATE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update

Got an error when ran update statement. 
For one record it worked fine, but for a chunk of records it gives me an error.

Also, why it tells me that 64801 row(s) affected and then 1 row(s) affected and then 0? How should I interpret that?

This is the script:

```
update tblQuotes
set QuoteStatusID = 11, --Not Taken Up
    QuoteStatusReasonID = 9 --"Not Competitive"
where CAST(EffectiveDate as DATE) < CAST('2013-11-27' as DATE)
and CompanyLocationGuid = '32828BB4-E1FA-489F-9764-75D8AF7A78F1' -- Plaza Insurance Company
and LineGUID = '623AA353-9DFE-4463-97D7-0FD398400B6D' --Commercial Auto
```

[image]

I added `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement, but it still won't work.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
update tblQuotes
set QuoteStatusID = 11, --Not Taken Up
    QuoteStatusReasonID = 9 --"Not Competitive"
where CAST(EffectiveDate as DATE) < CAST('2017-11-27' as DATE)
 AND CompanyLocationGuid = '32828BB4-E1FA-489F-9764-75D8AF7A78F1' -- Plaza Insurance Company
and LineGUID = '623AA353-9DFE-4463-97D7-0FD398400B6D' --Commercial Auto
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: looks like you have a trigger that checks transition of quote status is valid and rolls back the tran if it isnt.

Comment: can you share the script or part of the script that's giving you this error

Comment: Well, `rollback transaction` has to have corresponding `begin transaction`. Check value of `@@TRANCOUNT` - it's the number of pending transactions. You should check it before any alter to a database.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this is a "flaw", if not a "bug" in SQL Server. When you COMMIT a transaction, TRANCOUNT is decremented by 1. When you ROLLBACK any transaction, all transactions in the calling stack are rolled back! This means that any calling procedure that tries to commit or rollback will have this error and you've lost the integrity of your calling stack.

I worked through this when building a mechanism do do unit testing on SQL Server. I get around it by always using named transactions as shown in the example below. You can obviously also check XACT_STATE. The point is simply that, rather than blindly committing and rolling back anonymous transactions, if you manage transactions by name or transaction id you have better control.

For unit testing, I write a stored procedure as a test that calls the procedure under test. The unit test is in either serializable or snapshot mode and ONLY includes a rollback statement. I call the procedure under test, validate the results, build test output (pass/fail, parameters, etc.) as XML output, then everything gets rolled back. This gets around the need to build "mock data". I can use the data on any environment as the transaction is always rolled back.

```
--
-- get @procedure from object_name(@@procid)
-------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @procedure        SYSNAME = N'a_procedure_name_is_a_synonym_so_can_be_longer_than_a_transaction_name'
        , @transaction_id BIGINT;
DECLARE @transaction_name NVARCHAR(32) = RIGHT(@procedure + N'_tx', 32);

--
BEGIN TRANSACTION @transaction_name;

BEGIN
    SELECT @transaction_id = [transaction_id]
    FROM   [sys].[dm_tran_active_transactions]
    WHERE  [name] = @transaction_name;

    SELECT *
    FROM   [sys].[dm_tran_active_transactions]
    WHERE  [name] = @transaction_name;

-- Perform work here 
END;

IF EXISTS
   (SELECT *
    FROM   [sys].[dm_tran_active_transactions]
    WHERE  [name] = @transaction_name)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @transaction_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

This error states that in SQL Server, you have given a Commit or Commit Transaction without specifying a Begin Transaction or the number of commit transactions is greater than the number of begin transactions. To avoid this make sure you check the existing transactions on the current session before committing.

So a normal Commit Transaction will be updated as below

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I've added those statements. But it still not working. Gives me the same error. Can it be because of the trigger?

Comment: Oleg, referencing my answer above; that is the insidious thing about the flaw in the SQL Server architecture. If something in the calling stack executes a ROLLBACK, everything above it in the calling stack gets rolled back. The way to keep your code from erring out when this happens is as I noted, use named transactions, then only try to COMMIT or ROLLBACK if the name (if unique) or transaction id exists and XACT_STATE allows the action. Ref the XACT_STATE docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trigger, that making sure about the integrity of the QuoteStatusID. So im my WHERE clause I have to exactly specify what current status ID policy have to have in order to be updated.